# Google OAuth 2.0 SAMEORIGIN Error

Tags: javascript, oauth, google-api

This is a question as old as time. But how do I get around the SAMEORIGIN error when using googles javascript API?

From their example:

```
let clientId = 'CLIENT_ID';
let apiKey = 'API_KEY';
let scopes = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly';

gapi.client.setApiKey(apiKey);
setTimeout(() => {
  gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: clientId, scope: scopes, immediate: true}, (authResult) => {
    console.log(authResult);
  });
});
```

I get:

> Refused to display
>   '. . .'
>   in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.

I have my API Key set as a Browser Key. And the Client ID set as a Web Application.

I am trying to test this via localhost which may be a problem. So on the API Key I added http://localhost:8000 to Authorized JavaScript Origins- Which may not make sense but it was worth a shot I thought.

The API key is not restricted to any domain and there is no domain verification for the OAuth verification screen.

I've also tried running chrome with --disable-web-security but no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried `immediate: false`